# Python: How do I assign values according to first time reaching max value in column per group?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, assign

Thanks for reading this and trying to help me. I want to analyze what a student does after finishing the last question in a test. I am analyzing this in a pandas dataframe.

Currently I have among others the first two columns of the table below, however, I want to create a new column and assign values according to the first time the max value (question sequence #) of an individual student is hit. I want to create the third column but I do not know how.

Could someone help me with this?

I hope I gave all the needed details. Otherwise feel free to contact me. I know I am able to find the index of the max value with .idxmax(), but not per student and how to assign values before and after this.

| Student ID | Question sequence # | before or after last item? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Before or last item |
| 1 | 2 | Before or last item |
| 1 | 3 | Before or last item |
| 1 | 1 | after last item |
| 1 | 2 | after last item |
| 2 | 1 | Before or last item |
| 2 | 2 | Before or last item |
| 2 | 3 | Before or last item |
| 2 | 4 | Before or last item |
| 2 | 1 | after last item |
| 2 | 2 | after last item |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `groupby` with `idxmax` here. Then compare the index to the index with the highest value:

```
m = df.index > df.groupby('Student ID')['Question sequence #'].transform("idxmax")
df['before or after last item?'] = np.where(
    m, 
    "after last item", 
    "Before or last item"
)
```

```
    Student ID  Question sequence # before or after last item?
0            1                    1        Before or last item
1            1                    2        Before or last item
2            1                    3        Before or last item
3            1                    1            after last item
4            1                    2            after last item
5            2                    1        Before or last item
6            2                    2        Before or last item
7            2                    3        Before or last item
8            2                    4        Before or last item
9            2                    1            after last item
10           2                    2            after last item
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this fast answer! Have a great weekend :)